# Diode modeling in verilog a

Tags: diodes, photodiode

I am modeling a diode using verilog ams but I have a problem when I simulate its behaviour in different temperatures.

The simple equation of the diode (Id=IS∗(eVd/Vt−1)) is not enough because it gives me the inverse of the predicted results.

Could you help me to find a way to simulate the temperature dependency correctly?

Regards,

Comment: That does appear to be an attempt at the Schockley diode equation but are you using the exponent correctly (not shown correctly in your question)? \$I_D = I_S [e^{\frac{V_D}{V_T}} - 1]\$

Comment: Yes I use the Schockley equation, whith a given voltage if we increase temperature the current should increase too but it is not the case for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring reverse bias breakdown methods, most simulators just use

$$I_D = I_s\left( e^{\frac{V_d}{\eta U_T}} - 1\right)$$

- \$U_T = \frac{kT}{q}\$ is the thermal voltage, and depends on temperature
- \$\eta\$ is the *emission coefficient* or the *ideality factor*
- \$k\$ is Boltzmann's constant
- \$q\$ is the elementary charge
- \$I_s\$ is the saturation current and depends on temperature

Spice-based simulators use the following formula's for the saturation current:

$$I_s(T) = I_{s,T_0} \left( \frac{T}{T_0} \right) ^\frac{XTI}{\eta} e^{ \frac{q\cdot EG\cdot T_0 T}{\eta k (T - T_0)}}$$

\$T_0\$ is the temperature where the parameters were measured. \$XTI\$ is usually 2. \$EG\$ is called the *activation energy*, and is by default \$1.11\$ in most Spice simulators.